# Android Destroy current view from parent

Tags: android, layout, view, android-appcompat

I have a Parent activity that sets a view on Resume based on some check like this :

```
public class AppLockActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@BindView(R.id.btnSubmit)
Button submitButton;

private static final String TAG  = "AppLockActivity";
private static TimeElapsed timeElapsedInstance;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    timeElapsedInstance = TimeElapsed.getInstance();
    timeElapsedInstance.resetTime();
    timeElapsedInstance.setStartTime();
}

@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    //check if app has passed a time threshold
    if(timeElapsedInstance.getStartTime() != 0){
        timeElapsedInstance.setEndTime(Calendar.getInstance().getTimeInMillis());
        long threshold = timeElapsedInstance.getEndTime()-timeElapsedInstance.getStartTime();
        Log.d(TAG,"Threshold : "+threshold);
        //Current timeout threshold set to 30s
        if(threshold>30000){
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_app_lock);
            ButterKnife.bind(this);

        }else{
        }
    }

}

@OnClick(R.id.btnSubmit) void onSubmit() {
    //destroy current(Parent) view and show the previous
}
}
```

This activity is extended by other activities like MainAcitivty ,etc...

```
public class MainActivity extends AppLockActivity{
  @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
 }
}
```

When the app goes in background and is resumed the onResume function is called and based on the check the new View is set - R.layout.activity_app_lock. What I want to do is onClick of the submit button in this view I want to destroy the current view i.e (R.layout.activity_app_lock) and show the previous view that was in the child activity like MainActivity (R.layout.activiyt_main)...

Anybody have any idea how can I do this?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can actually call `setContentView` again with a different view.  All your bindings need to be reset and your `On_____Listeners` need to be cleared or else you'll get a memory leak. Other than that, it'll be up and ready for you to go.

Though I suggest an alternative approach to changing the layout.  Instead, create a new Activity that you start in replacement of the layout your currently submitting.  Then, rather than worrying about leaks, you just call `finish()` on the lock Activity when the user submits.  The effect would be the same and it would be more versatile (In my opinion).

Comment: I just launched a new activity as u suggested. You can see the changes here : https://github.com/Glucosio/glucosio-android/pull/325/files